# Move to another paired div using each

Tags: jquery, each

This seems simple enough but it has me stuck.
I'm finding multiple divs with the same class (getting a nearby href) and I want to post the results to other multiple divs (.div_2) with a different class. Removing/replacing what is currently in div_2.
 Can this be done with each?

```
$('.div_1').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).find('h3 a:first').attr('href');
    $('.div_2').html(url);
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jxEcv/

Comment: What issues are you have with your current implementation? Please post your HTML here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the div_1 and div_2 elements occur reliably in the same order, then the index of one can be used to refer to the corresponding element using eq():

```
$('.div_1').each(function (index, value) {
    var url = $(this).find('h3 a:first').attr('href');
    $('.div_2').eq(index).html(url);
});
```

It won't matter what relative-order they appear in, as long as there are, for example, three div_1's and three (corresponding) div_2's.

Comment: I should of been more clear that 'div_2' is always corresponding but is somewhere near 50 divs lower on the page than 'div_1'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.div_1').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).find('h3 a:first').attr('href');
    $(this).prev('.div_2').html(url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.div_2').html(function () { return $(this).next().find('a').attr('href'); });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jxEcv/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.div_1').each(function () {
    var url = $(this).find('h3 a:first').attr('href');
    $(this).prev('.div_2').empty().append(url);
});
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

$('.div_2') is a jQuery object, which contains an array of all .div_2 elements, not the element in reference to your .div_1. You need to look for the respective $('.div_2') with respect to .div_1

```
$('.div_1').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.find('h3 a:first').attr('href');
    $this.prev(".div_2").html(url);
});
```

Here is your updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jxEcv/2/